# Probability & Statistic on point estimate

Tags: statistics

May i know how do I calculate a point estimate of the values that separates the largest 10% of all values in the thickness distribution form the remaining 90%

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the "thickness distribution" is, but you are asking for an estimate of the $90^{th}$ percentile. There are a number of ways to do that. See [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section2/prc252.htm) for some simple approaches.